# nginx rewrite subdomain to file as a variable

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How do you get the subdomain as a variable to add in a rewrite?

**hello**.example.com should go to example.com/user.php?u=**hello** but still display as just **hello**.example.com

I'm currently doing http://example.com/users/**hello** but would like to have Tumblr style  domain names for users.

```
rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /user.php?u=$1 last;
```

Also, if there are pages like /settings/ after the subdomain hello.example.com/settings/ I'll need to rewrite to a settings.php

Answer (score 4):

Two things. Firstly you need to read the host variable to get the subdomain and set it to a variable which is used later. 
I used the variable $sub_domain and and then append the variable to to the URI.

```
if ($host ~* (.*)\.example\.com) {
     set $sub_domain $1;
     rewrite ^/user.php$ /user.php?u=$sub_domain
}
```

The rewrite line needs to be tweaked further. I have given an example here. Refer to the nginx in-built [variables documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables) for available options.